# Passing object to ngTrueValue fails

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

Can an object be the assigned value to `ngModel` when `<input type="checkbox">` is selected?

The following fails when I try to set the object `group` as `ng-true-value`:

```
<div ng-repeat="group in groups">
   <input type='checkbox' ng-model="array[$index]" ng-true-value="group">
</div>
```

Or, is there another way to achieve this?

Comment: Why do you need the actual object and not just a value from that group? Isn't `{{ group }}` enough?

Comment: less words.. what's group? ....   and do what? This is not the proper way to ask a question. Explain your issue clearly in words and explain the problems you have resolving it. We aren't mind readers

Comment: Did the answer below address your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is, *sort of*, possible with `ng-true-value` but you have to understand that `ng-true-value` expects a constant. In other words, if you did this:

```
<div ng-repeat="group in groups">
  <input type="checkbox" ng-model="array[$index]" ng-true-value="{{group}}">
</div>
```

and selected the first item, then the following will be true: `array[0] !== groups[0]`. In other words, you will get a copy of the object.

Instead you could do the following to assign the actual object:

```
<div ng-repeat="group in groups">
  <input type="checkbox" 
         ng-model="selected" 
         ng-change="arr[$index] = (selected && group) || undefined">
</div>
```